# Getting syntax error due to curly braces with multiple commands

Tags: bash

I am trying to run the following multiple commands a command prompt but I get syntax error near unexpected token '}'. The following page examples where it is working but I am getting the syntax error. I am running Ubuntu desktop 18.04.5. What am I missing? Thanks.

```
{echo "Today's date and time"; date;} > f1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a space after the `{`. The shell needs to see the `{` as a single token ("words"), but what it sees is `{echo` so when it gets to the final `}`, it doesn't know what to do with it:

```
{ echo "Today's date and time"; date;} > f1
```

Comment: Thanks terdon. That was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a space at the beginning :

```
 { echo "Today's date and time"; date;}
```